# Studies about button placement to download reports?

Tags: buttons, layout, call-to-action

Would it be more natural for the user to click under the text area or in a centralized area of actions.

In our example at http://www.bruxzir.com/science-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/, we have images on the left and text on the right. 
[image: Current Layout]

The button to download a larger image are under the image, which makes sense to though I am encouraging to just use a larger image to begin with.

The site was originally designed when internet speeds were slower, so the first designer wanted to be mindful of load time.

The "download image" makes sense on the left. But so far so is the "download report on the left."

[image: With both actions on left]

So would it make more sense to have all downloads on left. Perhaps as my new mockup below

[image]

Or under the content that they represent?

Comment: In my experaince the current trend is to have the full size image display on mouse over.  Where there are multiple image usually the first one is displayed full size, then as you mouseover others they are displayed.

Comment: @JamesJenkins oh ok, that is an excellent suggestion about the larger image on mouse over.

Comment: Should I make it an answer so you can accept it?  Or do you need more?

Comment: @JamesJenkins I would suggest you give some evidence that this is THE way to go.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Well the primary concern that I had was about button placement for downloading reports. The issue with images was just an additional consideration to give context.

Comment: Because the study is essentially an expansion of the text rather than the image, as a user I would expect the link to be on the right underneath the text. I think that's where I usually see a "See more..." type of link.

Answer (score 1):

I think where the download link is to be placed really should depend on what particular usability or user experience issue you are trying to address. To me there is no confusion about the actions, and there is no issue about the user being able to locate the link. Whether these are people who are likely to scan the images first to find reports, or read through the description wanting to get more details has to be determined from actual page statistics. Without some way to measure things like bounce rate or task completion (to test or compare between the designs), you won't have anything objective to work out whether the changes have any impact on the user experience of the site at all. I would suggest at least changing the colour of the link (even though I know it is the theme of the website) to a different shad of red since I find excessive red not generally a pleasant experience for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the website, I would suggest the following:

- Place all image related links on the left below the images as this clearly show the link between the two
- Place the download button on the right and if its not much of a change, I would suggest a rectangular button with background color the same as the heading's bg color & text in white.

A suggestion not related to question that I would like to share is that, you could give each of the article a border or a light background color with low opacity. This will help the users to clearly distinguish between posts.